# Read multiple JSON files into an array of Powershell objects and filter out those with the same value for a property

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, enumeration

It's my first time, so let me know if I'm doing something wrong with the layout of my question.

I have a lot of JSON files with filenames that follow a naming convention, i.e. file1.json, file2.json, etc. Each of which are likely to have multiple objects which look like:

```
[
    {
        "Forename":  "Jim",
        "Surname":  "Cook",
        "Gender":  "M",
        "DOB":  "12-03-1994"
    },
    {
        "Forename":  "Sarah",
        "Surname":  "Parker",
        "Gender":  "F",
        "DOB":  "01-02-1983"
    },
    {
        "Forename":  "Alan",
        "Surname":  "Flemming",
        "Gender":  "M",
        "DOB":  "27-10-1989"
    }
]
```

In Powershell, I would like to convert these JSON objects into Powershell objects and then select objects with the same value for a property, like people whose first name is "Jim".

So far I've achieved this:

```
@(Get-ChildItem "file*.json" | %{Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json}) | Where-Object {$_.Forename -eq "Jim"}
```

This works when there is only one file to work with, which outputs:

```
Forename Surname Gender DOB
-------- ------- ------ ---
Jim      Cook    M      12-03-1994
```

However it fails and outputs all objects when used with multiple files, as though the Where-Object is being ignored. The result can look like this:

```
Forename Surname  Gender DOB
-------- -------  ------ ---
Jim      Cook     M      12-03-1994
Sarah    Parker   F      01-02-1983
Alan     Flemming M      27-10-1989
Bill     Preston  M      04-07-1975
Helen    Smith    F      03-12-2001
```

Can someone please suggest what I'm doing wrong here and how it can be fixed to get the correct result? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that, **in PowerShell versions up to v6.x**,  **`ConvertFrom-Json` outputs (converted-from-)JSON arrays *as single* objects** rather than *element by element*, as is otherwise typical in PowerShell.

- **Note**: In **PowerShell [Core] 7.0**, the **behavior was changed** to align with the usual enumeration-of-elements behavior, and a `-NoEnumerate` switch was added as an opt-in to the old behavior.

This results in the *entire array* getting output by `Where-Object` if (at least) one of its *elements* has a `.ForeName` property with value `Jim`, thanks to [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).

The **workaround** is to force enumeration, which in the simplest case is achieved by **wrapping the `ConvertFrom-Json` call in `(...)`**:

```sh
Get-ChildItem file*.json | ForEach-Object {
  (Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName | ConvertFrom-Json)
} | Where-Object { $_.Forename -eq "Jim" }
```

<sup>Note that I've replaced `Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String` with `Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName` (PSv3+), which is both more concise and more efficient for retrieving a file's content as a single, multi-line string.</sup>